# DataTrigger with a custom color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I´m trying to set the `Foreground` color of a `Label` based on the color of the other control which is a `Border`.
If I use a predefined XAML color for the border it works, but if I use a custom RGB color, it does not.

The following example **works**, because the color used for the border is `blue`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=borderControl}" Value="blue">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
<Border x:Name="borderControl" Background="#ffecec" BorderBrush="blue" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10" Margin="20" CornerRadius="5">
    <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Content="This message is red if border color is blue" />
</Border>
```

The following example **does NOT work**, because the color used for the border is `#f5aca6`.

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=borderControl}" Value="#f5aca6">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
<Border x:Name="borderControl" Background="#ffecec" BorderBrush="#f5aca6" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10" Margin="20" CornerRadius="5">
    <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Content="This message is green and should be red" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the color that you assign to property of type [`Brush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brush?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.Brush);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) like `BorderBrush` will automatically be converted into a brush *instance* by a type converter. For solid colors like `#f5aca6` an instance of a [`SolidColorBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush?view=net-5.0) will be created behind the scenes. If you use one of the predefined brushes like [`Blue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes.blue?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Media_Brushes_Blue), you are actually accessing *static instances* on the [`Brushes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes?view=net-5.0) class.

Now why does it work for predefined brushes and not for custom colors? The brush types do not override equality comparers, so the `DataTrigger` will compare them *by reference*. Predefined brushes are static instances, so it is always the same reference. However, custom colors will create a *new instance* of a brush, therefore they are not equal to the predefined brushes by reference.

You can solve this issue by creating a brush instance of your custom color in XAML and using that.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomBorderBrush" Color="#f5aca6" />
   
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=borderControl}" Value="{StaticResource CustomBorderBrush}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

```
<Border x:Name="borderControl" Background="#ffecec" BorderBrush="{StaticResource CustomBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="10" Margin="20" CornerRadius="5">
   <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"Content="This message is green and should be red" />
</Border>
```

In the special case of having a solid color, you could alternatively compare the `Color` property of the brush in the style, but be aware that this fails for other brush types like [`GradientBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.gradientbrush?view=net-5.0).

```
<Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BorderBrush.Color, ElementName=borderControl}" Value="#f5aca6">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for you great answer and for improve my question, since English is not my first language.